# How use JSF tags (probably inputHidden) to set http request parameter with a fixed name?

Tags: jsf, el, servlet-filters, http-request-parameters

I have am using JSF. When I am submitting a form - the data from JSF tags (like h:inputText) are somehow passed in request to the server. I do not know how JSF rewrites it on request parameters or attributes (I not even that familiar with http request). I just know how to use 'el' langue. But now I have to add to a submit request a string, I a way that allow me read that string in a filter. So I want somehow use JSF tags (probably inputHidden) to set http request parameter with a fixed name (like "MySecretToken"), then In filter I could write:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

if ( isTokenValid( httpRequest.getParameter("MySecretToken") ))
     doThis(...);
else
     doThat(...);

     chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

So the problem is "How use JSF tags (probably inputHidden) to set http request parameter with a fixed name?".

Comment: JSF uses client identifiers to write the IDs of the form elements which then become the parameter names of the submitted parameters. The [getClientId](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) describes how these are built. You can also look at using options like [prependId](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/form.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to use the [`<f:param>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/param.html) in `<h:commandXxx>` component. It basically adds a HTTP request parameter with exactly the specified name and value.

```
<h:commandButton ...>
    <f:param name="MySecretToken" value="#{bean.mySecretToken}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

A more JSF-ish way would be to create a custom component for the job. E.g. `<my:token />`. You could even create a custom component event listener which automagically adds this custom component to the form everytime.